# How to use the least amount of memory to store a string in a hashset

Tags: java

I have a large amount of strings that need to be stored in a very compact fashion. Currently I am storing the strings (32 characters a-f/0-9) in `HashSet<byte[]>`. I am simply calling `.getBytes()` to get this.

My question is, is there a better way to store this data in a hashset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `HashSet<byte[]>` is broken anyway, as `byte[]` doesn't override `equals()` or `hashCode()`. Calling `getBytes()` without specifying a character encoding is generally a bad idea - it's probably okay if you've only got hex digits, but I would still avoid it where possible.

If your strings are always 32 hex digits, that's basically 16 bytes - have you considered either writing a custom collection for this, or possibly just encapsulating them in an object? Given that for any "normal" collection you've got to have an object of *some* description to represent the element, the object overhead is hard to get around - although with a custom collection you could just have two arrays of longs which you kept in sync. That would be about as compact a representation as you could probably find, but just an object with two `long` fields or four `int` fields would be my starting point. Then you can override `hashCode` and `equals` and actually get `HashSet` to work with value equality, instead of just reference identity... and you'll still be using less data per element than a byte array of 32 bytes.

Comment: Agreed.  If you have a very fixed data set/size, you can probably do some good optimization rather than storing as a string.

Comment: and how to keep two arrays in sync? how about map?

Comment: @DarthVader: I'd write a completely custom collection. Java collections don't work terribly nicely with primitive types, which is what we want in this case... but I'd start off just with a `HashSet<Simple16ByteValue>`.